# Permissions needed to "edit image"?

Tags: assets, permissions

What permissions do users need in order to access the "edit image" menu in assets?

Some users can't access this, but I can't see a specific permission for this listed under:

Settings > Users > User Groups

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3349) is what you are looking for

> When the deleteFilesAndFoldersInVolume permission is not set, the user cannot edit the image. And dragging files into other folders result in an error.